# What is (list.index() inside a for loop) complexity

Tags: python, list, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

For each number in (first list):
Second list.index(number) -> variable
Print (index of number in first list) and (variable)

Comment: Can you provide few sample input and output? I am having trouble understanding the question.

Comment: Very fishy that people are asking identical questions in such a short timeframe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67387382/can-anybody-tell-me-what-is-the-time-complexity-of-this-code

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have in your current methods is that you make placing *one* element dependent on the *entire* opposing list.  Instead, simply make a chart of where each element is in each list.

Use a dict.  Go through list1, filling in key:value to be the element and its index.  This gives you

```
{ 5: 0, 8: 1, 1: 2, 4: 3 }
```

Now, go through list 2.  Access each element; if it exists (use `get` for the fail-safe functionality), print the stored index (list1) and the current index (list2).  If it doesn't exist, then simply skip printing.

**O(N)** complexity.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the code:

```py
for searched in first: # O(n)
  i = second.index(searched) # O(m)
  print(i)
```

Then the answer is `O(n * m)`, where `n = len(first)`, `m = len(second)`.
It can be done in `O(n + m)` if you use dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map data structure to reduce time complexity to O(n)

**Step 1**: Traverse list one and stored indices of all values of list one in a map.
for eg; List1 = {5, 8, 1, 4} 
your map will be look like 
5 -> 0 
8 -> 1 
1 -> 2 
4 -> 3

**Step 2** : Now after storing values at list one, traverse list2 and check if an element present in a map or not, if it is present then print their indices otherwise skip that element 
for eg List2 = {1, 5, 4, 8}
Output: 
val = 1, 2 -> 0 
val = 5, 0 -> 1 
val = 4, 3 -> 2 
val = 8, 1 -> 3

Note: That implementation will only work when elements in both lists will be distinct. otherwise there will be more than one indices for a particular value.

If you use C++, then I will suggest you to use unordered_map as it work in O(1).

The time complexity of this implementation will be 
O( list1.size() + list2.size() )
and space complexity will be O( list1.size() )